# getting back slash in paste0

Tags: r, parsing, paste

I need to get the following string in R dynamically changing dates everytime.

```
'Rscript D:/get_data.r "2015-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 00:00:00"'
```

I am using following

```
date1 <- "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
date2 <- "2016-01-01 00:00:00"

paste0('Rscript D:/get_data.r "', date1, '" "', date2, '"')
```

But I am getting the following with slashes.

```
"Rscript D:/get_data.r \"2015-01-01 00:00:00\" \"2016-01-01 00:00:00\""
```

How do I get rid of slashes? **I need double quotes only around dates in the final output string.**

Comment: `date1` is declared twice. Where is `date2`?

Comment: @MaxPD corrected. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf('Rscript D:/get_data.r %s %s', date1, date2)
#[1] "Rscript D:/get_data.r 2015-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00"
```

If we need the quotes

```
cat(sprintf('Rscript D:/get_data.r "%s" "%s"', date1, date2),'\n')
#Rscript D:/get_data.r "2015-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Comment: but there are no double quotes around dates in the output.

Comment: @user3664020  The quotes within a string will show the escape character.  If it is just for printing, use `cat`

Comment: it is not for printing, need to create a string which i need to pass to the terminal.

Comment: @user3664020  It is not possible to have a string with `"` that don't have escape character.

Comment: i need to send `Rscript D:/get_data.r "2015-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 00:00:00" ` to the terminal from R to run using system() command. That is why was trying to create this string.  I need to send this dynamically with new dates everytime. How can I do this then?

Comment: @user3664020  Can you try `sprintf('Rscript D:/get_data.r %s %s', dQuote(date1), dQuote(date2))`   As I mentioned above, the way you described may not be possible.  Have you tried the one with escape quotes?

Comment: @user3664020  Even the one you mentioned at the beginning of the post also gives an escape character i.e. `'Rscript D:/get_data.r "2015-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 00:00:00"'
#[1] "Rscript D:/get_data.r \"2015-01-01 00:00:00\" \"2016-01-01 00:00:00\""`